# Two feature in different locations

Tags: wix

I am trying to make a wix installer.
i have two features defined. I want to be able to install each feature in a different location.

```
 <Feature Id='ServerInstallation' Title='Engine' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='TARGETDIR'>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id='ServerFileSystemGroup' />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id='RegistryGroup' />
</Feature>
```

I want to be able to put this anywhere on disk, with the default value c:\Program Files\ProductName\Feature1

```
 <Feature Id='ClientInstallation' Title='Moduletitle' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLLOCATION'>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id='ClientSystemGroup' />

  <Feature Id='Subfeatureid' Title='Subfeature' Level='1'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='SubfeatureSystemGroup' />
  </Feature>
</Feature>
```

I want to be able to put this anywhere on disk, with the default value c:\Program Files\ProductName\Feature2

But the two feature should be able to be installed in any non-related location.
I tried to define a root directory TARGETDIR and on the same level an INSTALLLOCATION but i get an error

*The Directory with Id 'INSTALLLOCATION' is not a valid root directory.  There may only be a single root directory per product or module and its Id attribute value must be 'TARGETDIR' and its Name attribute value must be 'SourceDir'.*

How can i setup this properly?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see your `<Directory>` structure, but in any case, you can't use `TARGETDIR` as a configurable directory. [`TARGETDIR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064.aspx) can only be used at the root, and everything goes inside.

I think yours should look something like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProductFolder" Name="ProductName">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR1" Name="Feature1" />    
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR2" Name="Feature2" /> 
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Then you can use `INSTALLDIR1` and `INSTALLDIR2` for your `ConfigurableDirectory`s.

**See also**

- http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/1/26/stackoverflow-what-does-namesourcedir-refer-to/
- http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Configurabble-Install-Directory-td5351039.html